# Send to mail recipient vbscript not longer working

Tags: email, vbscript, sendto

I used to use below VBscript to send files by mail as attachments to be able to add my signature in the e-mail message.

Since about two weeks the VBscript is showing an error every time I try to send a file. I tried to use normal "send to/mail recipient" and it works fine.
Would you advice how can this be solved?

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objArgs, OutApp, oNameSpace, oInbox, oEmailItem, olMailItem
Dim a, oAttachments, subjectStr, olFormatHTML
olMailItem = 0
olFormatHTML = 2
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments 'gets paths of selected files
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'opens Outlook
Set oEmailItem = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'opens new email
For a = 0 to objArgs.Count - 1
    Set oAttachments = oEmailItem.Attachments.Add(objArgs(a))
    subjectStr = subjectStr & Right(objArgs(a),Len(objArgs(a))-(InStrRev(objArgs(a),"\"))) & ", " 'recreates the default Subject e.g. Emailing: file1.doc, file2.xls
Next
If subjectStr = "" then subjectStr = "No Subject "
oEmailItem.Subject = "Emailing: " & Left(subjectStr, (Len(subjectStr)-2))
oEmailItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
oEmailItem.Display
```

Error message:

> Unable to execute - arguments list is too long

Comment: What is the error number, and which line is raising the error? How many arguments are you passing to the script?

Comment: there is no number for the error. i don't know which number is raising error. I put this script in send to menu and when i want to send attachments, I select files and right click to chose this script from send to.